# GDPR - If am am allowing user to post on twitter and Facebook from my IOS app?

Tags: european-union, gdpr

If am allowing user to post on twitter and Facebook from my IOS app, Do I have to get user consent ? If yes what do I have to mention in user consent ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The GDPR requires you to get consent from the data subject if *you* process the data subject's personal data.

Creating software and making it publicly available for use do *not* automatically result in you processing personal data, even if the software processes personal data, as long as that processing happens on devices and computer systems outside of your sphere of control.